# inserción múltiple con php

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un proyecto donde tengo que insertar varios productos al enviar el formulario y no he logrado como hacerlo. Por ejemplo tengo este campo que se pueden insertar múltiples veces (solo haré el ejemplo con esa columna porque sino sería bien largo el código):

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label class="ontrol-label">Producto</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productName" placeholder="Nombre Producto" name="productName" autocomplete="off" required="" maxlength="50" />
</div>
```

Y en otro archivo php se hace la siguiente lógica de insertar a la tabla:

```
$productName = $_POST['productName'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO product (product_name) VALUES ('$productName')";
                if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    $valid['success'] = true;
                    $valid['messages'] = "Successfully Added";
                    header('location:../product.php');  
                } else {
          $valid['success'] = false;
          $valid['messages'] = $connect->error;
       }

    $connect->close();
```

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para hacer múltiples consultas en una tabla vendría bien trabajar con matrices, ya que PHP usa la sintaxis de corchetes para convertir entradas de formulario en una matriz (guardar múltiples datos en una variable). Esto lo podrías aplicar en tus consultas con las tablas. Primero, tu atributo `name` vendría a ser así:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label class="ontrol-label">Producto</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productName" placeholder="Nombre Producto" name="productName[]" autocomplete="off" required="" maxlength="50" />
</div>
```

Y en tu consulta con las tablas, tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

> Agregamos un for que se repetirá `'count($productName)'` veces, donde `'count($productName)'` es la cantidad de elementos que tiene el arreglo (si la variable tiene 2 datos acumulados, el ciclo se inserción se repetirá 2 veces, 1 para cada dato). Mientras va repitiendo, va concatenando con la primera variable y formando una cadena.

```
$productName = $_POST['productName'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO product (product_name) VALUES ";

for($i = 0; $i < count($productName); $i++){
  $sql.="('".$productName[$i]."'),";
}
```

> Como vemos, la concatenación de la cadena siempre lleva una `,` al final para seguir concatenando con la siguiente cadena, pero cuando el ciclo for se detenga, la `,` seguirá estando al final y el query será incorrecto, por ello, tendremos que borrarlo de la siguiente forma.

```
$sql_arreglo = substr($sql, 0, -1);
```

> Y por último, le tendremos que añadir un `;` al final para finalizar la cadena y que se ejecute bien la consulta.

```
$sql_arreglo.= ";";
```

De esta forma, el query entenderá que estas haciendo varias inserciones a una tabla, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Lo veo mucho más sencillo y me sirvió, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

En realidad para que un campo se pueda insertar muchas veces tal y como pones en el ejemplo  el atributo `name` del `input` debe indicar que es un `array`  de la siguiente manera   `name="productName[]"`

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre Producto" name="productName[]" autocomplete="off" required="" maxlength="50" />
```

Dicho esto es momento de hacer el insert

```
 if(isset($_POST["productName"])){
      $cantidad = count($_POST['productName'][]);
      
      for ($i = 1; $i <= $cantidad; $i++) {
          $productName = $_POST['productName'][$id];
          
          $sql = "INSERT INTO product (product_name) VALUES ('$productName')";
                    if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                        $valid['success'] = true;
                        $valid['messages'] = "Successfully Added";
                        header('location:../product.php');  
                    } else {
              $valid['success'] = false;
              $valid['messages'] = $connect->error;
           }

          $connect->close();
          
          
      }
 }
```

Explicacion:

`count()` : Devuelve la cantidad de elmentos en un array.

`isset()` : Devuelve true si la variable esta definida

Comment: También es otra forma de hacerlo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda