# PHP no me permite subir múltiples archivos

Tags: php, fileupload

Estoy tratando de subir múltiples archivos con PHP. Tengo puesto el atributo multiple en el input correspondiente pero al subir los archivos y hacer un var_dump del array descubro que solo se queda con el último archivo añadido. No sé qué puede estar pasando.

Este es el index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Editor de textos </title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="gestor.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="archivos" id="archivos" multiple> <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Aquí es donde recojo los archivos.

Y este es el gestor.php

```
<?= $archivos["archivos"] = $_FILES["archivos"]; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> nube </title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <?php
      foreach($archivos as $archivo) {
        echo "<li>".$archivo['name']."</li>";
      }
    ?>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Y esta es la salida que me da

[image: Al subir múltiples archivos solo se sube el último archivo]

Comment: Algo no me cuadra. El error aparece en la línea `1` y lo que tienes en la línea `1` es esto `<!DOCTYPE html>` ¿Seguro que nos estás mostrando el archivo `gestor.php` correcto? Y es que ahí ni siquiera se ve como lees a la superglobal `$_FILES`. Muéstranos el contenido de `gestor.php` en cuanto tal, como archivo `.php`, no lo que se produce en el navegador.

Comment: Por alguna razón no se guardó lo que había en la primera linea

Comment: Intenta subir más de un archivo y dinos qué muestra un `var_dump($_FILES);` en ese caso.

Comment: Muestra null. Como si estuviera vacío. Pero en otras pruebas que he hecho solo conseguí que se quedara con el último archivo subido

Comment: Puede que tengas restricciones con algunas extensiones de archivos o cosas así ¿? O con respecto al tamaño de los archivos... ¿Tienes código Javascript del lado del cliente?

Comment: No, solo hay php. Y los archivos que he intentado subir eran un par de imágenes

Comment: ¿De qué tamaño? PHP puede tener restricciones en cuanto al tamaño de los archivos.

Comment: No llegan a los 300KB entre los dos

Comment: Es muy raro. ¿Revisaste el `.htaccess`, no sea que haya restricciones de extensiones de archivos o cosas así?

Comment: ¿Cómo compruebo el htaccess y que debo buscar?

Comment: Hay un archivo `.htaccess` por lo general, y los tipos de archivo se pueden restringir con la directiva `<Files>` o de otro modo. Pero ten cuidado de modificar ese archivo si no sabes cómo hacerlo, sólo revisa si algo que parezca a restricción de extensiones de archivo.

Comment: No encuentro nada raro en ese archivo. O igual no es ese archivo o igual no sé buscar esa directiva

Comment: No sé, pero si `var_dump($_FILES);` muestra `null` es porque los archivos no están subiendo por algún motivo. Quizá el log de errores pueda darte alguna pista.

Comment: Ya he revisado los logs y no dicen nada que pueda servir. El último log fue de hace un par de horas y no tiene nada que ver con la subida de archivos

Comment: cambia `name="archivos"` a `name="archivos[]"`. Si quieres saber más sobre esto, mira [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/553956/inserci%c3%b3n-m%c3%baltiple-con-php)

Comment: ¿Los archivos que intentas subir no tienen nombres raros, con acentos, espacios, caracteres especiales, etc?

Comment: No abras PHP con `<?=` sino con `<?php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si deseas subir varios archivos en un array, debes poner el **name** como tal.

O sea, en lugar de esto:

```
<input type="file" name="archivos" id="archivos" multiple>
```

ponlo así:

```
<input type="file" name="archivos[]" id="archivos" multiple>
```

Y en el bucle ponlo así:

```
foreach($_FILES["archivos"]["name"] as $index=>$nombrearchivo) {
    echo "<li>".$nombrearchivo."</li>";
}
```

Ya nos dirás si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Ya he probado a hacerlo como indicas, pero el error persiste:
Warning: Undefined array key "archivos" in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestor.php on line 1
Ese es el error que me lanza, y al pasar archivos por el var dump lo sigue marcando como null

Comment: En mis pruebas locales me pasaba lo mismo que a ti y luego, cambiando eso, me ha funcionado.  He ampliado mi respuesta, revísala de nuevo.

Comment: Nada, me sigue fallando. He puesto un var dump directamente a $_FILES y me dice que el array no está definido. Lo he comprobado varias veces y está todo bien. No entiendo nada.

Comment: Pues yo tampoco... entiendo que cada vez que lo pruebas seleccionas los archivos (y no le das simplemente a F5 o recargar la página). Sino no funcionará.

Comment: Revisa de nuevo tu código para que sea igual que el de la pregunta (y luego adaptas mi respuesta). Si has hecho modificaciones quizás te has cargado alguna cosa sin querer.

Comment: Ya está solucionado. Todas las pruebas que he hecho he vuelto a mandar los archivos. Pero ahora por alguna razón le ha dado por funcionar y me detecta los dos archivos

Comment: No puedo marcar la pregunta como resuelta porque no sé qué es lo que ha pasado

Comment: Si no has hecho el cambio del **name** que he indicado en mi respuesta entonces no te funcionará, por lo tanto entiendo que lo has hecho.